# “The buildings are owned by him.” Is this a verbal stative passive or an adjectival passive?

Tags: passive-voice, participles, deverbal-adjectives

In terms of what I’ve seen: *“Adjectival passives always have stative interpretations, whereas verbal passives can either have a dynamic or a stative interpretation.”*

So…. If I have a sentence, such as:

*“The buildings are owned by him.”*

Would this be a verbal stative passive, or just an adjectival passive?

Obviously I can transform it to:

*“He owns the buildings.”*

But to me, it almost seems like it’s active even in the “passive” (air-quotes just in case) version. Like, if I change “be” to, say:

*The buildings “remain” owned by him..”*

Or

*“The buildings “seem” owned by him”*

It obviously fails the “very” test, but the above two tests seem to work out. See:

*“The buildings are very owned by him (ungrammatical).”*

But doesn’t the ability to switch “be” with “remain” or “seem” imply it could be an adjective here?

Thus, I guess my question is, how can I tell if this, or other constructions with stative verbs are “verbal” stative passives, or simply “adjectival” passives?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140727/discussion-on-question-by-taylor-b-the-buildings-are-owned-by-him--is-this-a).